# Symbolic Pattern - Five Different Symbols used only ONCE, one missing symbol. Help Needed

Tags: pattern, symbols

[image: The pattern itself]

It is supposedly an arithmetic progression.

The examples (not clues/no correlation) the teacher gave for us to get familiar with the "quiz" were these:

1, 2, 3, ***4***, 5    (+1)

2, 4, 7, ***11***, 16  (+n)

Can you solve it?

Comment: Is this a homework problem, because it sounds that way?

Comment: More like a fun after-lesson quiz. The teacher teaches us physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like it's just mirrored numbers incrementing by one each time...

Although, I would have thought '1' would be more like an upward pointing arrow as they seem to mostly be mirrored about the horizontal centre.

[image: My Answer]

Comment: Yup, saw your previous (now deleted) answer. This is what I came up with:

[![Mine][1]][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/FstvGHP

Comment: Yeah, I edited the answer to include the bit about the number '1'. It seems that some of them are mirrored through the middle (6 and possibly 3), and the others are mirrored on the left edge, a little confusing.

Comment: I guess it just depends how you write numbers, I would have had 2 more like an underlined heart shape.

Comment: Exactly, but since 2 is so recognizable and a heart is a famously symmetrical shape it would have been too easy.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one. The answer is:

> [image]

Because:

> each entry in the sequence is the corresponding natural number (1,2,3,4,5,6) reflected in a vertical axis and placed next to itself.

Comment: I'm very impressed!

Answer (score 0):

All the signs in this list are the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6  (like the hint 1,2,3,**4**,5 (+1)) but with a mirrored copy attached to them.

example (sorry for bad drawing)

[image]

The missing one is 4, so the missing symbol will be something like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is what I drew. Thank you all!

[image]